# How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f = x^3 + x + 1$.
How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f)$ have? Write out all of the elements of this field, and find the inverse of each nonzero element.

I know that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and thus has no roots. How would I calculate what kinds of elements are contained in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f)$? What's the form of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f)$?

Comment: Since $f$ is irreducible the number of elements is $2^{deg(f)}=2^3$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response! I’ve calculated all of the elements but how would I find the inverse of each element? For $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ where $f = x^2 + 1$, I was able to use $x^2 \equiv -1$. Do I use the same quotient ring here?

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time seeing this. What would the inverse of $x^2 + 1$ be for $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$?

Comment: I make it easier for you. Find a polynomial $g$ such that $g\cdot (x^2+1)=1$ and note that $1=x^3+x$ by definition in this quotient ring.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of $\Bbb Z_2[x]/(f)$ has the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+(f)$
where $a_0,a_1,a_2\in\Bbb Z_2$. There are two possibilities for each $a_i$
so $2\times2\times2$ in all.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the detailed response. How would I go about finding the inverse of each element? For $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f)$ and $f = x^2 + 1$, I was able to use $x^2 \equiv -1$, how would I approach $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f)$ for $f = x^3 + x + 1$?